# Htaccess RewriteRule for optional trailing slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^(la|en|me)/?(.*)$ /go/$2 [R=302,L]
```

When user visit `/la/route-1` it will be redirected to `/go/route-1`.

Visit `/en` it will be redirected to `/go/`.

It works great, but I got an issue about this:

If someone visit `/eng/route-1` it will be redirected to `/go/g/route-1`, it shouldn't trigger redirection.

Have any idea with that?

Answer (score 1):

This will probably do:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:la|en|me)(?:/(.*))?$ /go/$1 /go/$1 [R=302,L]
```

You capture the separating slash along with the path component you want to capture.

Note: I also suggest to make the first group a "non capturing group" (`(?: ... )`), since you are not interested in what it currently captures. Consequently you have to use `$1` then in the target path.

Comment: Although from the question it would seem the "trailing slash" (first slash) on the request needs to be _optional_, but always enforced on the target. ie. `/en` redirects to `/go/` (and by extension `/en/` would also redirect to `/go/`).

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks for pointing that out. I made the second group optional.

Comment: Simply making the second group optional does not enforce the "trailing slash" on the target (`/en` redirects to `/go`, not `/go/` as would seem to be the intention). You need to take the slash out of the capturing group and include the slash in the _substitution_. eg. `^(?:la|en|me)(?:/(.*))?$ /go/$1`